# How can disable BECKHOFF Device Manager on startup?

Tags: twincat, twincat-hmi

I'm trying to publish my `HMI` on `CX2030`, so I followed the Beckhoff site's instructions for publishing the HMI. When I turn on the PC, the BECKHOFF Device manager starts with the login page simultaneously but in different tabs. how can I fix this issue? (disable show the Beckhoff device manager on start up).
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Good question. No clue. I couldn't find any entry if you enter `shell:startup` or `shell:common startup` in the Run program. There was also no task scheduled, nor an entry in Task Manager > Startup.

Comment: Very good question indeed. I remember a setting like "do not start automatically" but I can't find it anywhere. Who designs systems like these...? Annoying. EDIT: Does the last comment help from here: https://www.sps-forum.de/threads/beckhoff-device-manager-deaktivieren.99139/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed it thanks to the link from Quirzo:

1. Press start, type **Run** and enter `regedit`.
2. (Optional) Save your current registry via **File > Export**.
3. Go to **Edit > Find** and type `localhost/config`. For me the device manager was at the following location:

   [image: registry key location of the device manager]
4. Right clikc **StartSecurityWizard** and select **Delete**.
5. Restart the PLC and the Device Manager should no longer start automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to go to task manager>startup. There you will find an entry for Windows command processor. If you disable it, it won't open anymore.